# *ngFor Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined when given an Observable of type array

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, reactive-programming, rxjs

This is pretty straight forward, so I'm not sure why it's not working.

I have a service giving me an observable. 
I have a couple of rxjs streams which contribute to it like so:

```
search(searchTerm: string {

  this.searchStream = this.http.get("${this.baseUrl}searchq=${searchTerm}");

  this.resultStream = this.searchStream.map(
    data => {
      let obj = data.json();
      return {
        artists: obj.artists.items,
        albums: obj.albums.items,
        tracks: obj.tracks.items
      };
    },
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('getRepos completed')
  );

  this.albumSearchStream = this.resultStream.map(
    searchResults => {
      console.log("mapping albums");
      return searchResults.albums
    },
    err => console.log("unable to get albums")
  );
  this.albumSearchStream.subscribe(
    albums => console.log(albums)
  );
}
```

Long story short, after a request the **albumSearchStream** gets an array of type **EnvAlbum**.

This is all happening within a service on Search.

This service is being injected into my Page controller, and in the constructor I am doing

```
this.albumResults = this.spotifyService.albumSearchStream;
```

where **albumResults** is going to be **Observable of type EnvAlbum[]**.

Then in the template I am using a basic ngFor on this observable like so:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let result of albumResults | async" >
        <ion-card-header>
            {{ result }}
        </ion-card-header>
    </ion-card>
```

However, then I get the following error:
[image]

I am beyond stumped as to why this error is occurring.

*NB: On subscribe, it is correctly outputting an array of objects*

Comment: What version of Angular 2 are you using? Could be a bug in Angular 2 because we only have release candidates at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem that `albumResults` isn't a property of your component (it will be undefined) at the beginning so the `async` pipe can't subscribe on it. It seems to be set when you click to trigger the `search` method...

You could try to wrap the `ngFor` within an `ngIf` with the desugared expression

```
<template [ngIf]="albumResults"> <------
  <ion-card *ngFor="let result of albumResults | async" >
    <ion-card-header>
      {{ result }}
    </ion-card-header>
  </ion-card>
</template>
```

or initialize the albumResults with a fake observable.

**Edit**

I would refactor your service code this way:

albumResults = new Subject();

```
search(searchTerm: string) {
  this.searchStream = this.http.get(...);

  this.resultStream = this.searchStream.map(
    data => {
      let obj = data/*.json()*/;
      return {
        artists: obj.artists.items,
        albums: obj.albums.items,
        tracks: obj.tracks.items
      };
    }
  );

  this.albumSearchStream = this.resultStream.map(
    searchResults => {
      return searchResults.albums
    }
  );
  this.albumSearchStream.subscribe(
    albums => {
      this.albumResults.next(albums);
    }
  );
}
```

and set the `albumResults` property in your component this way:

```
constructor(private spotifyService:SpotifyService) {
  this.albumResults = this.spotifyService.albumResults;
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/IrsZ9P3wff2YXyjRRGTw?p=preview.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not resolve it. albumResults is a property, and if I place anything within that [ngIf], it will show. Echoing album results into the page shows [object Object]

Comment: In fact I think the problem is that your observable changes at each search request. Don't know if it's exactly the cause of the problem. I created a plunkr on how I refactor your service code: https://plnkr.co/edit/IrsZ9P3wff2YXyjRRGTw?p=preview. I updated accordingly my answer...

Comment: Perfect, thanks Thierry. Appreciate all the effort, I'm much happier with the service looking like this.
That said, I'm not certain why we would expose a Subject rather than an observable. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: Great! You're welcome! In fact, a subject provides both observable and observer into a single element. A subject is a specific observable. Without it you need to use something like that: `var observable = Observable.create(observer => this.observer = observer);` and use then the `next` method of the observer...

Comment: I see. I think it will be a while longer before I'm able to mentally parse reactive properly, but that helps a lot.

Comment: It's a different way to think application ;-) This tutorial could help you: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754. It helped me a lot in the past...